# Qml не работают сигналы форм

Tags: qt5, qml

Я новичек в Qml и не могу понять, почему не работает.

Есть 3 файла `FirstForm.ui.qml, LastForm.ui.qml, main.qml`

Добавил строчку в

```
mail.qml
FirstForm {

}
```

После этого в Qml Desinger я пытаюсь добавить кнопку и установить сигнал. Меня перекидывает в main.qml  и добавляет строку.

```
mail.qml
FirstForm {
     button.onClicked: {}                  
}
```

Но, чтобы я туда не добавил например `console.log("Test message!")` Ничего не происходит. Ладно подумал я, создал новый файл qml. Который автоматически создал и форму под этот файл. В форме добавил кнопку, добавил якобы сигнал, в testFile.qml добавилась такая же строчка `button.onClicked: {}`. Результат как и раньше, никакого эффекта. Почему так? Если я описываю кнопку просто в qml файле, всё работает. Но, мне нужна именно форма.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в том, что строка `FirstForm { }` была добавлена перед

```
StackView {
        id: stackView
        initialItem: "qmlsrc/First.qml"
        anchors.fill: parent
    }
```